# Unexpected behavior using if .. or .. Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm reading in a list of samples from a text file and in that list every now and then there is a "channel n" checkpoint. The file is terminated with the text `eof`. The code that works until it hits the `eof` which it obviously cant cast as a `float`

```
log = open("mq_test.txt", 'r')
data = []
for count, sample in enumerate(log):
    if "channel" not in sample:
        data.append(float(sample))
        
print(count)
log.close()
```

So to get rid of the `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'eof\n'` I added an `or` to my `if` as so,

```
log = open("mq_test.txt", 'r')
data = []
for count, sample in enumerate(log):
    if "channel" not in sample or "eof" not in sample:
        data.append(float(sample))
        
print(count)
log.close()
```

And now I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'channel 00\n'`

So my solution has been to nest the `if`s & that works.

Could somebody explain to me why the `or` condition failed though?

Comment: It did not fail.  `"eof"` was not in sample, therefore the `or` condition _as a whole_ was true.  You might want `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `and` operator not `or` since both `"channel"` and `"eof"` are strings and they cannot be typecasted into float, also try to do grouping so:

```py
log = open("mq_test.txt", 'r')
data = []
for count, sample in enumerate(log):
    if ("channel" not in sample) and ("eof" not in sample):
        data.append(float(sample))
        
print(count)
log.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a logic issue which "and" might be used instead of "or"